# Limit of $\frac1n\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, taylor-expansion

In my homework I have to find limit (by interpreting it as an appropriately chosen function as the limit of integral sums):

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+n)} (1)$.
$$
$$
Solution:

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+n)} =
\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} ln(\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+n)}) =
\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} ln(\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{n^n(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{2}{n})(1+\frac{3}{n})...(1+\frac{n}{n})}) = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} ln(\frac{1}{n} n\sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{2}{n})(1+\frac{3}{n})...(1+\frac{n}{n})}) = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} ln((1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{2}{n})(1+\frac{3}{n})...(1+\frac{n}{n}))^{1/n} = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} ln((1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{2}{n})(1+\frac{3}{n})...(1+\frac{n}{n})) = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} ln(1+\frac{k}{n}) = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} ln(1+\frac{k}{n})$
$$
$$
Note that function $f(x)=ln(1+x)$ is continuous in $[-1,1]$. Find integral $\int ln(1+x) dx = (x+1) ln(1+x)-x+C$.

Then $\int_{-1}^{1} ln(1+x)dx = ln(4)-2$.
$$
$$
Assume that that limit $(1)$ is A. We show that $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$: $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $n\geq N \Longrightarrow $ $|\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} ln(1+\frac{k}{n})-A|<\epsilon$.

Suppose that $\mathfrak{T}$ is $[-1,1]$ set of subdivisions. Fix. $\epsilon > 0$. That $f$ is integrative $[-1,1]$, then exist $\delta >0$:

$\forall$ $T = T[x_0,...,x_n]\in \mathfrak{T}$ $\forall \xi=(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)\in[x_0,x_1]\times...\times[x_{n-1},x_n]$

$\lambda(T)<\delta \Longrightarrow |\sum_{k=1}^{n} ln(1+\xi_k) (x_k-x_{k-1})-A|<\epsilon$.

Which $N$ to choose? Is this right solution so far?

Comment: A taylor expansion is an expansion of a continuous function near some value.  This appears to be an expression defined on the natural numbers.  What is $f(.1)$, say?  What value are you expanding near?

Comment: If the problem is to find the limit you write down, then I would suggest using Stirling's formula, not Taylor series.

Comment: Sorry but where do you see any "series" involved? // What did you try to (actually) solve this?

Comment: Maybe work on its logarithm, and try to interpret it as a Riemann sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you push the $\frac{1}{n}$ inside the radical, and then take the natural log of your expression, you get

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left( \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) + \ln\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right) + \cdots \ln\left(1+\frac{n}{n}\right) \right).$$

Which looks a lot like a Riemann sum, eh?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: let us introduce the sequence $a_n = \frac{(2n)!}{n! n^n}$. We have
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)n^n}{(n+1)(n+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{4\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$
hence $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\color{red}{\large\frac{4}{e}}$. Cesàro theorem then implies this is also the limit of $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ as $n\to +\infty$.

---

Non-trivial corollary. $e>\frac{8}{3}$ is a straightforward consequence of Jensen's inequality, since
$$ \frac{4}{e}=\exp\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+x)\,dx <\int_{0}^{1}(1+x)\,dx=\frac{3}{2}.$$